# SQL Server 2016 and creating External Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a database in SQL Server 2016. I have a linked server to an SAP HANA database as well. What I am trying to do is add a table from the HANA database to my database as an external data table. Is this possible?

I am not sure about the best way to do it. I have tried the create external table, but I keep getting the syntax error near 'External.'

Basically have a table in the SQL Server database that is linked to the SAP HANA table, so that I can treat the table as any other table. I know I can use openquery to create stored procedures, but I am wondering if I can create it as a linked table in my database.

Comment: @dk; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not possible.
Creating an external table is for PolyBase to access data stored in a Hadoop cluster or Azure blob storage PolyBase external table that references data stored in a Hadoop cluster or Azure blob storage.
But SAP HANA is another RDBMS.

Comment: Is there no other way?